How Does a Highly Imbalanced Sample Affect the Type 1 and 2 errors of A/B Test Results?
Suppose I have an A/B test where the two sample sizes are very different in sizes, (i.e. 1000 and 100). I am wondering if there is a framework for how I can think about what generally happens to the Type 1 and 2 errors? For example, I see in this answer in another post that

If the smallest sample size is the one with highest variance the test
will have inflated Type I error.

I am wondering why this is so. My intuition is that if we were to examine the $t$ statistic, it consists of a difference in means divided by a standard error:
$$
t=\frac{\bar{X}_1-\bar{X}_2}{SE}
$$
It would seem the $SE$ would be inflated, due to both small sample size and higher variance generally, leader to a smaller $t$-statistic, making it harder to reject the null. This would seem to imply the Type 1 error, the probability of incorrectly rejecting the null given it is true, would be decreased since generally its harder to reject the null now.
However, this is at odds with the above answer and quote. Why is it? thanks.

The article you refenced is about the t-test with and without equal variance assumptions. You can see it's so first assuming an equal variance t-test. Then use a t-test for unequal variances and unequal sample sizes and see how it affects the power of the test and the type i error rate.

I suggest you read this wiki post, on the "Behrens-Fisher" problem. It should provide all the explanations you need wrt t-test. Btw, this Beherens-Fisher problem applies to other tests as well (e.g. non-parametric Mann-Whitney U test).
